# How to create HTML tags?

Tags: php, querypath

Unline phpQuery, Running

```
echo qp('<div>s</div>')->html();
```

I expect to get `<div>s</div>` but it returns a complete document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>s</div></body></html>
```

How do I prevent it from adding `doctype`, `html` and `body` tags?

Currently, as a workaround I can use `qp('<div>s</div>')->top('body *')->html();` for that. But I seek a cleaner way.

Comment: Just `echo "<div>S</div>";`?

Comment: @Qirel What do you mean by that?!! I need to build markup using qp methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/support-querypath/tk3ZxLBbEEE):

```
echo qp('<div>s</div>')->top('body')->html();
```

Comment: Incidentally, that's the first Google result for `querypath without doctype`.

Comment: It returns `<body>
  <div>s</div>
</body>`. Btw I hope there is a cleaner method for that.

Comment: @PHPst Well, go read the docs. I'm not sure how much cleaner it can get, and it looks like `top` takes a selector of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just KISS (Keep It Simple and Stupid)

```
echo "<div>s</div>"
```

This will output:

```
<div>s</div>
```

Using `qp` for that purpose will be an overkill/and will waste your precious time for no-reason IMHO.